# Sort an array of alphabetic and numeric string-type elements ASC, but with numeric elements after alphabetic elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, numeric, alphabetical

I have an array of values which are either all-letters or all-numbers and need to sort them in an ascending fashion.  Additionally, I want all-numeric values to be moved to the end of the array so that they occur after all of the non-numeric values.

```
$test = ["def", "yz", "abc", "jkl", "123", "789", "stu"];
```

If I run `sort()` on it I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 789
    [2] => abc
    [3] => def
    [4] => jkl
    [5] => stu
    [6] => yz
)
```

but I'd like to see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def
    [2] => jkl
    [3] => stu
    [4] => yz
    [5] => 123
    [6] => 789
)
```

I tried `array_reverse()`, but that didn't seem to change anything. I'm at a loss for how to get the numbers last, but in ascending order.

Comment: you can try dividing the array into two: strings and integers solely, then apply sort, and then merge them together.

Comment: Lots of good answers, was hoping for a simple function like `sort()` but, I guess overall the answers below make sense. Thank you all, I will give them a shot, and come back with which one works best for my need

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you need is sort but with a custom comparison function (usort). 
The following code will get it done:

```
function myComparison($a, $b){
    if(is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b))
        return 1;
    else if(!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b))
        return -1;
    else
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
} 
$test = array("def", "yz", "abc", "jkl", "123", "789", "stu");
usort ( $test , 'myComparison' );
```

Answer (score 7):

You could convert your numbers to integers before sorting:

```
$array = array("def", "yz", "abc", "jkl", "123", "789", "stu");

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (ctype_digit($value)) {
        $array[$key] = intval($value);
    }
}

sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => abc
  [1] => def
  [2] => jkl
  [3] => stu
  [4] => yz
  [5] => 123
  [6] => 789
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following code is separate the data in two arrays: one is numerical the other is not and sort it and merge it.

```
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();

$foreach ($arr as $val) {

if (is_numeric($val)) {array_push($arr2, $val); } 
else {array_push($arr1, $val);}

}
```

so you have to separate arrays whit numeric and non-numeric

```
sort($arr2);
sort($arr1);

$test = array_merge($arr2,$arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a custom comparison function, but this sounds like more trouble than it's worth.  I'd use `sort`, and then handle that output accordingly.  It's not clear how you want to use it, but a simple way might be:

```
sort($test);
foreach ($test as $index=>$value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
       $test[] = $value;
       unset($test[$index]);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

`usort` will probably be faster and it's going to do the comparisions once, while the other solutions mentioned thus far may be a little slower as they require iterating over some or all of the array before or after the sort

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to engage any iterated processing for this task -- and therefore should not.

Use `array_multisort()` to sort the array numerically, then as strings (normally).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gM0lk))

```
array_multisort($test, SORT_NUMERIC, $test);
```