# How do I sort mysql query column that is varchar numerically and alphabetically at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sorting

This column used to be integer type, but I needed to change it to varchar because the codes being used are not just numbers. they can be numbers and letters.

This is what it was when it was integer and it worked good, but now I need a different query that sorts better when letters are mixed in.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY operation_code ASC";
```

Here are all the different attempts I have tried and I can't get it to work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as unsigned)"; //Cast your column value to an integer explicitly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as unsigned) ASC"; //Cast your column value to an integer explicitly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY operation_code * 1"; //Cast your column value to an integer implicitly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY operation_code * 1 ASC"; //Cast your column value to an integer implicitly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY operation_code * 1, operation_code"; //mixed string and number?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as int)"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as int) ASC"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as INTEGER)"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as INTEGER) ASC"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY ABS(operation_code)";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY ABS(operation_code) ASC";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as float)"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as float) ASC"; //doesn't work
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as decimal(38,10))";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operation_codes ORDER BY cast(operation_code as decimal(38,10)) ASC";
```

All the ones that say don't work, do not spit out any results at all. The other ones spit out results, but don't sort the way I'm trying to sort.

Here is what happens for the ones that work. They all work the same way.

```
001
002
02B <--out of place
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
015
020
021
029
030
etc.
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
015
020
021
029
02B <-- in correct place
030
etc.
```

The one with the letter B, which has 02 before it should be by other ones that are 02, preferably at the end of the 02's because after numbers should be letters, but instead the one with the letter B is wedging itself between 00's and 01's.

What I find strange is when I go to database manager (navicat) and i sort by that column ascending, it does it correct with 02B right before 030, but with a query so it displays on a webpage, I can't make the same thing happen.

Comment: I might be missing something, but ordering by that column should place `02B` right after `029` unless you are ordering by something else first or using some odd trick. Thats where it should be alphabetically without casting/changing datatypes. Casting it to a number would place it after `002` simply because they would both convert to `2`. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a7f0/2

Comment: yeah i just noticed when i went back to the 1st query, it worked properly. what happened was, the numeric digits were not like this when they were integer type: 001, 002, 003, etc. they were like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. when i switched to varchar, the sorting went haywire and when i started using convert string to integer it worked properly again except for that 02B one. I didn't think to go back to first query after adding the zeros on the small numbers. i was just trying to fix string to integer method. anyway it's working properly now with original query and the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried sorting it in PHP instead with a function like [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

Here is an example that does what you are trying to accomplish:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590138/5399365