# PHP sort array keys by alphabetically and then numerically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort, ksort

I am trying to sort an array (with both alphabetic and numeric keys) by keys where the alphabetic keys will come first alphabetically and then numeric keys numerically.

Tried `ksort` with all the available flags, however that didn't help. Tried several SO answers, but none of them served my purpose. Here is an example of the the array I have..

```
$array = array(
    'Bat' => array(),
    'Dog' => array(),
    'Apple' => array(),
    'Cat' => array(),
    1 => array(),
    3 => array(),
    2 => array(),
    4 => array()
);
```

I need to sort it like this:

```
$array = array(
    'Apple' => array(),
    'Bat' => array(),
    'Cat' => array(),
    'Dog' => array(),
    0 => array(),
    1 => array(),
    2 => array(),
    3 => array()
);
```

What I understand from a SO answer that it might need a custom function to sort using the `usort` function. That's where I am lost. Any help or guide to the proper direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://eval.in/1049257

Comment: @splash58 The shortest solution. You should put that into an answer.

Comment: @splash58 I cannot reproduce the issue: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/535d93dcd5640417018e0e6c49493971f421945c

Comment: I'm not sure that understand how it works :) - https://eval.in/1050759

Comment: @splash58 ...I should have used ksort() to explain...  I can dream up a sample set that reproduces the improperly sorted output.   http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b10fd19dd1e367ad1f239d690b2caedd4037fa4

Comment: @mickmackusa Oh!!! you are about this - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bf5489a21a0b9f4db98727a699c674bdc4341ee ?

Comment: @splash58 Whoops my previous comment `can` should have read `can't`. I `can't ` find any sample input that ksort gets wrong (regarding numeric keys).

Comment: I understand. Seems, you are right - it works always with any alphabetic index. I'm too lazy to look the source of the function, but I too can not imagine of an example of a not correct work

Comment: Kind of related: [Sort an array of alphabetic and numeric string-type elements ASC, but with numeric elements after alphabetic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12590002/2943403)

Answer (score 5):

If you use only english alphabet and digits, usual ksort function works fine

```
ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1049257)

Comment: Strange. `ksort` was returning the numeric keys first when I tested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ha!  Wish I would have read your answer before I bothered to write such a comprehensive answer (with a less efficient/direct snippet).  Oh well, there's some valuable insights in it that future researchers may find helpful.  Any clue why the OP's input array wasn't obeying `ksort()`?

Comment: @Abhik Does this not actually provide the desired result in your project?  Can we see a more realistic representation of your project data?  What php version are you on?

Comment: @mickmackusa I see two variants: problem XY or using non-english letters in real project.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am using PHP7.2. The `ksort` actually sorting the array both alphabetically and numerically. However, I needed alphabetic keys first, then numeric keys. The `ksort` was doing quite the opposite, it was returning the numeric keys first and then alphabetic keys.

Comment: Yes, I understand your desired result.  The trouble is, we cannot reproduce the issue with ksort.  We are trying to figure out _how_ it could have been misbehaving..

Answer (score 3):

As @splash58 states, [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) is all that is required.

That said, if your project data is ordering numeric data before alphabetical and you need to reverse the order of those groups...

[uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) is the most direct/appropriate function for this job.

*Choose your key evaluating function carefully:

- [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) has a broad definition of what qualifies as `true` -- see the manual.
- [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) (and its alias [is_integer()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php)) is very strict in checking the data type.  Importantly, a string key like `"1"` will evaluate to `false`.
- [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php), while requiring all characters to be numeric, does not work on non-string type values.  Importantly, a non-string key like `8` will evaluate to `false`.

If you are using php7, you can make good use the [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) (`<=>`).  If your php version is sub-7, you can use whatever old-skool comparison you like.

My solution allows the spaceship operator to order non-integers before integers, then sort those values ASC.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc0d113ce60dfe86e628316a32e440277ddc2642))

```
$array = [
    2 => [],
    'Bat' => [],
    'Dog' => [],
    12 => [],
    'être' => [],
    'Cat' => [],
    1 => [],
    3 => [],
    'Apple' => [],
    4 => []
];

uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return [is_int($a), $a] <=> [is_int($b), $b];
});

var_export($array);
```

The `is_int()` calls will return `true` or `false`. These are respectively compared as `1` and `0`. Since sorting ASC, this means that `false` evaluations will come before `true` evaluations.

Output: (exactly the same as `ksort()`)

Comment: You can do `return $b <=> $a;` because any "not-dogit" string is less then any digit ?

Comment: Hmm. I guess I didn't scope beyond the sample data.  I didn't think that far.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't mind the question.  I have managed achieve bu using a custom function. I am posting the answer here to help if someone faces this issue.

```
function ev_sort_array( $array ) {
    $alp = array();
    $num = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_numeric($key) ) {
            $num[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $alp[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    ksort( $alp );
    ksort( $num );

    return array_merge( $alp, $num );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use uksort this way:

```
$array = array(
'Bat' => array(),
'Dog' => array(),
'Apple' => array(),
'Cat' => array(),
1 => array(),
3 => array(),
2 => array(),
4 => array()
); 
uksort($array,function($a,$b){
    if(is_int($a)&&is_int($b)) return $a-$b;
    if(is_int($a)&&!is_int($b)) return 1;
    if(!is_int($a)&&is_int($b)) return -1;
    return strnatcasecmp($a,$b);
});
print_r($array);
```

the output is as expected:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
        )

    [Bat] => Array
        (
        )

    [Cat] => Array
        (
        )

    [Dog] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

)
```