# Sort array alphabetically then numerically in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Refer to this post [php-sort-array-alphabetically-then-numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590002/php-sort-array-alphabetically-then-numerically)

It can't solve my problem.

I have an array name `$test`, if `print_r($test)` will show

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 1
            [masterroom] => B4-G-3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 2
            [masterroom] => B4-G-1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 7
            [masterroom] => B4-1-2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 8
            [masterroom] => B4-1-1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 9
            [masterroom] => B4-1-10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 10
            [masterroom] => B4-G-10
        )
)
```

And I try below (refer to above link's answer):

```
function myComparison($a, $b){
    if(is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b))
        return 1;
    else if(!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b))
        return -1;
    else
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
} 
usort ( $test , 'myComparison' );
```

The result are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 1
            [masterroom] => B4-G-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 2
            [masterroom] => B4-G-3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 7
            [masterroom] => B4-1-1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 8
            [masterroom] => B4-1-2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 9
            [masterroom] => B4-1-10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 10
            [masterroom] => B4-G-10
        )
)
```

But I want it to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 1
            [masterroom] => B4-G-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 2
            [masterroom] => B4-G-3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 10
            [masterroom] => B4-G-10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 7
            [masterroom] => B4-1-1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 8
            [masterroom] => B4-1-2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [hrid] => 9
            [masterroom] => B4-1-10
        )

)
```

Thank you.

Comment: In the current data you have `[hrid] => 1
            [masterroom] => B4-G-3` and in the expected result there is `[hrid] => 1
            [masterroom] => B4-G-1` Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should see if you could update your PHP. Thou this should work as of `5.5`

```
<?php

$array = [
  [
    "hrid" => 1,
    "masterroom" => "B4-G-3"
  ],
  [
    "hrid" => 2,
    "masterroom" => "B4-G-1"
  ],
  [
    "hrid" => 7,
    "masterroom" => "B4-1-2"
  ],
  [
    "hrid" => 8,
    "masterroom" => "B4-1-1"
  ], [
    "hrid" => 9,
    "masterroom" => "B4-1-10"
  ],
  [
    "hrid" => 10,
    "masterroom" => "B4-G-10"
  ]
];

$masterroom  = array_column($array, 'masterroom');
$hrid = array_column($array, 'hrid');

array_multisort($masterroom, SORT_NATURAL, $hrid, SORT_ASC, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Breathing example: https://3v4l.org/NaMqS PHP 5.5+
Breathing example: https://3v4l.org/Bc88G Pre PHP 5.5

Comment: means doesn't have function can work at 5.2.8 version php?

Comment: added another example for pre 5.5

Comment: @SweeHong You might want to upgrade your PHP. [5.2.8 has lots of security vulnerabilities.](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=74&product_id=128&version_id=67434&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=107&sha=29a108bdb9d907b8964228d5d4509ac207a48ada)